# Correctly Printing For Loops in Java

Tags: java

I have been working on this program for a few hours and the code is working correctly but I can't seem to get it to print out correctly, it should just be printing once for each value, such as:

number: 6

dividers: 2 3 6 1

prime: is not prime

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO0SV.png)

Can anyone help? Screenshot is attached. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random randomNums = new Random();

    int count;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 37; i++) { 

      count = randomNums.nextInt(100) + 1;
      System.out.println("number " + count); 

    for (int b = 1; b<=count; b++) {
        if (count % b == 0) {
            System.out.println("dividers " + b);
        }

    }
    for (int a = 2; a< count; a++) {
        if (count % a == 0) {
             System.out.println("is not prime");   
         }
         if (count % a != 0) {
             System.out.println("is prime");
         }
       }    
     }    
   }    
 }
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= 37; i++) { ` why are you doing this?

Comment: what is you expected output.  Please tell use what is wrong?

Comment: shouldn't you check how many possible values of counts are dividers and then `(count % a == 0)` ?

Comment: I need to print a randomly generated number 37 times, and it prints one count per time, 37 times, but when it gets down to the prime section, it's printing many times, and when it gets to dividers, it prints the word dividers for all multiples instead of just once. Please see the output attached.

Comment: @Millie surely you can see from the code why it's doing those things?  Perhaps if you only want the word "dividers" to appear once, you should print it _outside_ the inner loop, not inside it.  And if you don't want every single value of `a` to print either "is prime" or "is not prime", then maybe you shouldn't print these words inside the inner loop either.

Comment: How can I print outside of the for loop?

Comment: You could put something like `System.out.print("Dividers: ");` before the second `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to write this code :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random randomNums = new Random();

    int count;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 37; i++) { 

      count = randomNums.nextInt(100) + 1;
      System.out.println("number " + count); 
    String dividers = "";
    for (int b = 1; b<=count; b++) {
        if (count % b == 0) {
            dividers += b.toString() +" ";
        }

    }
    // control the print beside loop
    System.out.println("dividers " + dividers);
    // add the control for whether prime
    bool prime = true;
    for (int a = 2; a< count; a++) {
        if (count % a == 0) {
             System.out.println("prime : is not prime");
             // add the control for skip loop
             prime = false;
             break;   
         }
     }
     if(prime){
     System.out.println("prime : is prime");
     }    
   }    
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

based upon your logic, I am guessing that if you decide that a number is **not** a prime then that is the final result,

so

```
boolean isPrime = true;
String dividers = "";
for (int a = 2; a< count; a++) {
    if (count % a == 0) {
         isPrime = false;
         dividers += a+" ";
     }
} 

if (isPrime) {
  System.out.println ("is Prime");
} else {
  System.out.println ("dividers "+dividers);
  System.out.println ("is not Prime");
}
```

Comment: He might want to look at the dividers if the number is not prime